# PHP compare arrays and replace values

Tags: php, arrays, replace

i have two e-mail lists from different sources (MySQL, Excel), similar two my
example. I created two arrays in php two compare them.
The "$mail_old" array is the main list with several hundred addresses, and in "$mail_new" 
there are the changes. the names are the same, but some of the domains changed.

first i want to check which of the new addresses don't occur in the old list, which
works just fine.but i don't find a way to replace them, array_replace() doesn't seem to help here.
array_diff() also worked to check for differences, but i don't get any further.

here is what i got so far, it would be great if someone could give me a hint how 
to get the old addresses replaced by the new ones.

Thanks a lot!

```html
<?php
    $mail_old = array('peter@example.com', 'paul@example.org', 'max@example.com', 'mary@example.com', 'john@example.com', 'steve@example.org', 'sue@example.com', 'lisa@example.com', 'teo@example.com',);
    $mail_new = array('peter@example.org', 'paul@example.org', 'john@example.org', 'steve@example.org');

    foreach ($mail_new as $changed) {
        if (!in_array($changed, $mail_old)) {
            echo 'Address ' . $changed . ' is new.<br />';
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Which old addresses are supposed to be replaced? Your example doesn't have any addresses where the domain changed.

Comment: What happens if there are two addresses with the same name in different domains? `john@example1.org, john@example2.org`?

Comment: i mean something like "peter@example.com", which should be replaced by "peter@example.org"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make an associative array that's keyed off the name in `$mail_old`:

```
$mail_by_name = array();
foreach ($mail_old as $i => $addr) {
    list ($name, $domain) = explode('@', $addr);
    $mail_by_name[$name] = $i;
}
```

Then test each name in the new array against this:

```
foreach ($mail_new as $changed) {
    list($name, $domain) = explode('@', $changed);
    if (isset($mail_by_name[$name])) {
        if ($mail_old[$mail_by_name[$name]] != $changed) {
            echo 'Address ' . $mail_old[$mail_by_name[$name]] . ' changed to ' . $changed . '.</br>';
            $mail_old[$mail_by_name[$name]] = $changed;
        }
    } else {
        echo 'Address ' . $changed . ' is new.<br />';
    }
}
```